# Should I use a controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom-events

In my ruby on rails application my application lists some records and I have button filters that update the elements in the page without refreshing the page.

Right now I use jJavascript onclick events on my buttons to show/hide the records in my page, but somehow I feel that I should be using a controller. I feel that I have too much Javascript in my index.html erb file.

Is the correct way of filtering records (without page refresh) on an erb index page done using a controller or is it ok using Javascript?

Comment: depends, a controller would give you updated data.

Comment: This can't be answered, depends of your project. If you need to give a fluid navigation to your users, you need to use javascript, otherwise I would keep the page refresh by simplicity. If you need updated data, can use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing the right thing, but i would just filter client-side.

Doing another request for filtering what you already have is useless in this case. Consider reorganizing your javascripts in a simpler way. There are lots of javascript frameworks that can help you in this job nowadays, such as:

- [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/),
- [backbons.js](http://backbonejs.org/),
- [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)